# Blender running very slow

Tags: modeling

Blender is running extremely slow for me. I am just in the edit mode in the 3D-Viewport and just moving a few vertices takes like 4-5 seconds. I am working on very simple models and when I look at the performance in my task manager my GPU stay under 10%, my CPU is around 20% and I am using around 30% of my memory. 
The same project ran fine just yesterday.

What I have tried:
- Restart Blender
- Restart PC
- Check for updates of basically everything
- Activate CUDA

Running:
v2.79
gtx970m
i7-4710HQ
16 GB

Comment: If the project was running fine yesterday that means that something changed in your computer (not likely not a blender related issue unless you changed versions). It is likely you are yet another victim of an OS update (using windows?). Try updating or re-installing the drivers for the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any modifiers on your project? If so try hit the little eye icon, so you cant "see" it. It will still be rendered, but your pc wont have to work so hard while you are still working on your project.

Answer (score 1):

Double check if you're not running through an animation (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to pause play animations if you don't have the timeline up).

If that doesn't work, grab DDU uninstaller from guru3D here (http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) and uninstall all your NVIDIA drivers. This thing wont erase the CUDA toolkit, so don't worry about that!

Let me know if it worked, otherwise we can go from there